# How to run manage.py in Eclipse Pydev Interactive Console

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev, interactive-shell

I am trying to run 
manage.py to validate models (as: manage.py validate) in the Interactive Shell of a Django project (called djangonew) using Pydev

The PYTHONPATH is set to include /djangonew ... so import djangonew and then dir(djangonew) actually gives me a name as 'settings' in the subfolder /djangonew/djangonew

but at the command-line I am unable run manage.py (and even find it)

How do I solve this issue? Thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click on project, open menu django-> custom command

and type verify ( or other command after "manage.py")